# Jasmine test:error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following code:

```
angular.module('ps.workspaces').config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.factory('workspacesNonCompliance', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return {
      NonComplianceReasons: [
        {name: $filter('translate')('NONCOMPLIANT.ALL'), noncompliant_properties: '' },
        {name: $filter('translate')('NONCOMPLIANT.JAIL_BREAK_DETECTION'), noncompliant_properties: 'jail_break_detection' },
        {name: $filter('translate')('NONCOMPLIANT.COMPLIANCE_ROOTED_DETECTION'), noncompliant_properties: 'compliance_rooted_detection' },
        {name: $filter('translate')('NONCOMPLIANT.COMPLIANCE_USB_DEBUGGING'), noncompliant_properties: 'compliance_usb_debugging'},
        {name: $filter('translate')('NONCOMPLIANT.POLICY_EXPIRED'), noncompliant_properties: 'policy_expired'}
      ]
    };
  }]);
}]);
```

My module is :

```
angular.module('ps.workspaces', [
  'ps.workspaces.workspacesDirective',
  'ps.workspaces.workspacesFactories'
]);
```

My test is :

```
describe('Tests for workspacesNonCompliance /', function() {
  var workspacesNonCompliance,
      $provider,
      $filter;

  // beforeEach(module('ps.workspaces'));
  // beforeEach(module('ps.workspaces.workspacesDirective'));
  // beforeEach(module('ps.workspaces.workspacesFactories'));

  beforeEach(function(){
    angular.module('ps.workspaces', [
      'ps.workspaces.workspacesDirective',
      'ps.workspaces.workspacesFactories'
    ]);
 });

  describe('workspacesNonCompliance is array of noncompliance reasons /', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      inject(function ($injector) {
        workspacesNonCompliance = $injector.get('workspacesNonCompliance');
        $filter = $injector.get('$filter');

      });
    });

    it('workspacesNonCompliance has array of noncompliance reasons', function () {
      console.log('*******  workspacesNonCompliance ', workspacesNonCompliance);
      expect(workspacesNonCompliance.NonComplianceReasons).toContain({name: $filter('translate')('NONCOMPLIANT.ALL'), noncompliant_properties: '' });
    });

  });
});
```

Ran the test and got the error message:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: workspacesNonComplianceProvider <- workspacesNonCompliance
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.18/$injector/unpr?p0=workspacesNonComplianceProvider%20%3C-%20workspacesNonCompliance
    at /Users/joannepham/git/pws/console-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
    at /Users/joannepham/git/pws/console-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4031:19

Couldn't figure out what need to be fix in this case. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `ps.workspaces.workspacesDirective` and `ps.workspaces.workspacesFactories` has. But the main issue here is, the `workspacesNonCompliance` is not injected properly. That's why it's coming as `undefined` and hence the error.

Your test file should be something like:

```js
describe('Tests for workspacesNonCompliance /', function() {
  var workspacesNonCompliance, $provider, $filter;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('ps.workspaces');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function(_workspacesNonCompliance_) {
    workspacesNonCompliance = _workspacesNonCompliance_;
  }));

  describe('workspacesNonCompliance', function() {
    it('should have workspacesNonCompliance as defined', function() {
      expect(workspacesNonCompliance).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.